# remove the pipe "|" character when first item is not selected [logic error]

Tags: python

I have the following script that is suppose to build the detection string that I will modify my config file with on a specific session under key "detection_pattern" (ie: "detect_pattern" = (car|dog|person)) ,I am trying to build this string but I want the script to remove the "|" character if previous object is not selected.

[(the string that will be built out of the chosen items in the image would be (|person|truck) now I need to start with the item and remove the "|" when previous item is not selected), I hope what I am asking is not confusing you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw5QL.png)

this is how I am building the string:

```
detectstr="("
print(detectstr)
if inallobj != 'none':
    detectstr +=inallobj
    print(detectstr)
if animals != 'none':
    detectstr += "|"+animals
    print(detectstr)
if humans != 'none':
    detectstr += "|"+humans
    print(detectstr)
if things != 'none':
    detectstr += "|"+things
    print(detectstr)
detectstr +=")"
```

The ouput will be (inallobj|animals|humans|things) if all items are selected ,now say we don't select the first but the rest output would (|animals|humans|things) instead of (animals|humans|things) which is the output I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your `detectstr` is (|animals|humans|things), you can fix this issue replacing "(|" by "(" at the end of your code.

```py
detectstr = detectstr.replace("(|", "(")
```

However, you can do the following to make your code more readable (just in case it helps) by using the string's `"".join(...)` method.

```py
all_items = [inallobj, animals, humans, things]
detectstr = "(" + "|".join([item for item in all_items if item != "none"]) + ")"
```

In this way, we create the list of valid objects with the comphesion list (eliminating the values that are "none") and join the remaining elements with the character "|".

Comment: Thanks man this worked just like I wanted  and thank you for the explanation ,I can see where I was missing it.